# Why do adding ARMA noise have no effect on ACF and PACF?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, acf-pacf

I do an interrupted time series analysis and try to add an ARMA process using gls() function, but it seems like it has no or little effect.

Why does it look like there still is autocorrelation??
I tries with different values for p and q but its basically the same result.

```
model_1 <- gls(outcome ~ time + level_change + trend_change + July + December,
          data=df_int)
model_2 <- gls(outcome ~ time + level_change + trend_change + July + December,
          data=df_int, 
          correlation = corARMA( p=2, q=2, form = ~time ), method="ML"  )

acf2(  model_1$residuals, max.lag = 24  )
acf2(  model_2$residuals, max.lag = 24  )
```

Here time is discrete time variable, level_change is step function, trend_change is 0 ut to post-intervention and July and December are Dirac's delta functions or pulse functions.

Results Model_1

[image]

[image]

Results Model_2

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

Since there was questions about if there where autocorrelation I present the following example. And my question remains: why do adding ARMA noise do not change ACF og PACF? Does the $residuals not include the altered noise term?

```
t = seq(1:100)
y = 2*t + arima.sim(n=100, model=list( ma = c(2,1) ) )
df = data.frame("t" = t, "y" = y)

model_1 <- gls( y~t, data=df)
model_2 <- gls( y~t, data=df, correlation = corARMA( q=2, form = ~t ), method="ML"  )

acf2(model_1$residuals)
acf2(model_2$residuals)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don’ t have significant ACs or PACs as you may see from the fact that the ACF and PACF remain well within the respective confidence interval for basically all lags.. so you have sample estimates that are not significant and do not have statistical evidence to conclude that those estimate ACs or PACs are different from 0 in the true distribution

Comment: Re "Why does it look like there still is autocorrelation:" Exactly what evidence of autocorrelation do you see? I cannot find a single significant coefficient in any of your three graphics.

Comment: To me the ACF plot for both indicates a lag of 2. And the PACF also shows that lag 2 should be considered.  Why do you guys disagree with that? So if the adding ARMA noise do not have any significant effect the apparent lag is just by chance and not real?

Comment: it may happen that you see some “fractional touch” in a bar at some lag.. many times it is just some noise in the data/sample.. for example, if you use a larger sample taken from the same true distribution or you bootstrap, then you see that significance vanishing.. I tell you so from my experience.. notice for example the following contradiction: your PACF is always not significant although the ACF SEEMS to be significant at lag 2 because there is a “fractional touch”. That is why we use also PACF